# Origin of Jet production: Active Galactic Nuclei

Tags: astrophysics, relativistic-jets

According to [Netzer's book on Active Galactic Nuclei](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107021510) (AGN), [pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production) ($\gamma \gamma \leftrightarrow e^+ e^-$) which causes [AGN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_galactic_nucleus) jets presumably happens in *"the corona of the central accretion disk"* or *"inside the γ -ray jet"*. Is there any evidence for these as the origins of the jet, except that these are believed to be highly dense areas?